# handle long running application

Tags: android

I want to develop a application which will continue to run in background for infinity time.
but my application stop running after 1 or 2 days.

I m using service for this which will start a thread to run continuously.

Is there is any other way to handle long running application??

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Android service is entirely immune to being killed off by the OS, especially if the system is running low on resources. If your service has a memory leak or other problem, it could be forcing the system to look for ways to unclog itself.

Answer (score -1):

You need to build your long running task as a service, so it can contend with being killed, so that it restarts itself automatically.

```
public class MyService extends Service
{
    private Timer myTimer;

    class MyTask extends TimerTask
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            // do work
        }
    }

    myTimer = new Timer();
    myTimer.schedule( new MyTask(), 1000, 1000 * 60 * 5 );
}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html